# Spring boot - Persist a @onetomany entity

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, persistence, one-to-many

First time I try to persist a one to many entity. I got the "one" part correctly persisted, not the "many".

However, when reading data, everything goes fine.

"one" snippet :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_orderInfo")
public class OrderInfo {
    public OrderInfo() {

    }

    @Id
    @Column(name="typeName")
    private String typeName;

    @OneToMany( fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="orderInfo")
    private Set<ReticleInfo> reticles = new HashSet<>();

    public Set<ReticleInfo> getReticles() {
        return reticles;
    }

    public void setReticles(Set<ReticleInfo> reticles) {
        this.reticles = reticles;
    }
```

"many" snippet

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_reticle")
public class ReticleInfo {
    public ReticleInfo() {}

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;


    @ManyToOne( fetch = FetchType.LAZY) 
    @NotFound(  action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    @JoinColumn(name="typeName", nullable=false, insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private OrderInfo orderInfo;
```

The whole stuff is managed by JpaRepository

In a POST controller I do :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/main", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String testPOST(@RequestBody OrderInfo orderinfo) throws JsonProcessingException {

        System.out.println("POST here");

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String jsonInString = mapper.writeValueAsString(orderinfo);
        System.out.println("OrderInfo CTRL GET JS: " +jsonInString);
        System.out.println("");

        System.out.println("SAVE orderinfo");       
        orderInfoService.save(orderinfo);
        System.out.println("SAVED orderinfo");
```

The controller received a JSON string which is well formed. I checked on client side, and the "jsonInString" in the controller is correct as well.

I read some posts talking about that, I feel the problem is in my setter, but i can't figure out how to fix it.

Any help to persist my data will be appreciate. Thanks
Alak

Answer (score 0):

Just clean up the annotations and change to eager instead of lazy

"ONE"

```
    @OneToMany( fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="orderInfo")
    private Set<ReticleInfo> reticles = new HashSet<>();

    public Set<ReticleInfo> getReticles() {
        return reticles;
    }
```

"MANY"

```
@ManyToOne
@NotFound(  action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
@JoinColumn(name="typeName", nullable=false, insertable=false, updatable=false)
private OrderInfo orderInfo;

    public void setReticles(Set<ReticleInfo> reticles) {
        this.reticles = reticles;
    }
```

May it help someone else